# Error handling using JSONDecoder in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I am using `JSONDecoder()` in Swift and need to get better error messages.

Within the debug description (for example) I can see messages like "The given data was not valid JSON", but I need to know it is that rather than a network error (for example).

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = data {
   do {
      // process data

   } catch let error {
      // can access error.localizedDescription but seemingly nothing else
   }
}
```

I tried to cast to a `DecodingError`, but this does not seem to reveal more information. I certainly don't need the string - even an error code is much more helpful than this...

Comment: You have to cast the error to specific type to access the properties. Check out documentation for more details. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html

Comment: I know, I tried DecodingError. But it has no more detail than error alone.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried? It will help us to get more context of your issue.

Comment: print ("Error in reading data", error as! DecodingError)
                    print ("error", error.localizedDescription)
                    let decerr = error as! DecodingError
                    print (decerr.errorDescription)
                    print ("resaon", decerr.errorDescription)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

**Never** print `error.localizedDescription` in a decoding `catch` block. This returns a quite meaningless generic error message. Print always the `error` instance. Then you get the desired information.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = data {
   do {
      // process data

   } catch  {
      print(error)
   }
}
```

Or for the **full** set of errors use

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
if let data = data {
    do {
       // process data
    } catch let DecodingError.dataCorrupted(context) {
        print(context)
    } catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, context) {
        print("Key '\(key)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
    } catch let DecodingError.valueNotFound(value, context) {
        print("Value '\(value)' not found:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
    } catch let DecodingError.typeMismatch(type, context)  {
        print("Type '\(type)' mismatch:", context.debugDescription)
        print("codingPath:", context.codingPath)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
    }
}
```

Comment: `localizedDescription` should only be used if you need to display something to the end user.

Comment: I really like this answer. The only difference - for my own debugging -was omitting the `context` variable as it was too verbose.  `catch let DecodingError.keyNotFound(key, _) {
                        print("[!]Key '\(key)' not found")`

Comment: Can you get access to the property that was type mismatched? Say a field came back as an Int when I'm expecting a String, I want to set a default value for that property in that case

Comment: @infiltratingtree This makes no sense, because when an error occurs the decoding process will be interrupted and terminated.

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining properly. I want to know which field caused the decoding error. Is there any way to get that info?

Comment: The error shows the coding path and the expected and found type.