# Trouble parsing json from Scryfall

Tags: ios, json, parsing

So... I'm new to this. Been trying to teach myself how to program since maybe April. But I've always been tach . So... disclaimer out of the way...

I'm trying to make a Magic the Gathing based app. I'm trying to use Scryfall's database as a backend (so I don't have to catalog all 20,000 cards myself). But I'm running into errors parsing the json.

I've tried following along with Hacking with Swift's video series. I've tried two main ways.

Method 1. Downloading the bulk data, saving it to the project, and parsing it locally.

Method 2. Using URLSession.

Both times I get stuck at the same spot.

`if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)`

Somehow that part always fails. It works ONLY if I paste (a very small) part of the json as  `let json = """ [{ stuff: stuff, more stuff: more stuff}]"""` directly into the main .swift file. But any time I either use `Bundle.main.path(forResource: " nameOfFile", ofType: "json")` or URLSession it completly fails at the decode line.

- Theory 1. Scryfall isn't using json that conforms to Codable?
- Theory 2. My struct to hold the data isn't "catching" the decoded data correctly.

[Scryfall API](https://scryfall.com/docs/api)

[hacking with Swift > Codable cheat sheet](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/119/codable-cheat-sheet)

[hacking with Swift > Sending and receiving Codable data with URLSession and SwiftUI](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/sending-and-receiving-codable-data-with-urlsession-and-swiftui)

edit: [crosspost to Reddit > iOSDev](https://www.reddit.com/r/iosdev/comments/hq4kym/n00b_question_maybe/)

Answer (score 0):

Your „Response“-Class probably isn‘t completely correct. You can use something line quicktype to generate the model class.

You can also use a JSON-Validator to validate the json from their site (https://jsonlint.com), but I think there‘s no fault from their side

Also take a look at Error-Handling from JSON-Decoder: [Error handling using JSONDecoder in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389926/error-handling-using-jsondecoder-in-swift)

Without more details, I can‘t give you more help. Try posting a snippet (response model + code) so we can analyse the issue.