# Xcode - API Failing When Search Size is Greater Than 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, api, get

When fetching data from the iTunes API `https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(search)&entity=software&limit=14`, the fetch fails if the limit is a larger number (e.g. 30, 40, 50 etc.). The limit is denoted by `limit=14` found at the end of the URL. 14 is the number of results returned. This can be changed to any number.

When making the call in Postman, I can enter the limit as any number and it works without error. Additionally, when running the api with a large number in XCtest, the test passes. It only seems to fail when making the call live in the app.

The failure occurs in the guard let statement. In the code below, if the number is too large (e.g. 50), it prints "failed to fetch data" - indicating that there is a URL issue. When using a smaller number (e.g. 10), the fetch is successful and data returns in my table view. You can also change the search term. Currently I have it set to "Apple".

Below is the code for the API:

```
 import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Response: Codable {
  var resultCount: Int
  var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
  var screenshotUrls, ipadScreenshotUrls, appletvScreenshotUrls: [String]
  var artworkUrl60, artworkUrl512, artworkUrl100, artistViewUrl: String
  var supportedDevices, advisories: [String]
  var isGameCenterEnabled: Bool
  var features: [String]
  var kind, minimumOsVersion, trackCensoredName, fileSizeBytes: String
  var contentAdvisoryRating: String
  var genreIds: [String]
  var primaryGenreName, artistName, trackContentRating, trackName, releaseDate, sellerName, currentVersionReleaseDate, releaseNotes, version: String
  var primaryGenreId: Int
  var currency, description: String
  var price: Double
  var averageUserRating: Double
}

    class API {
  var storedData = Response(resultCount: Int.init(), results: [])
  func loadData(search: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Response) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=\(search)&entity=software&limit=40") else {
      print("failed to fetch data")
      return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
      if let data = data {
        if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.storedData.resultCount = response.resultCount
            self.storedData.results = response.results
            completionHandler(self.storedData)
          }
          return
        }
      }
      print("failed \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknown error")")
    }
    .resume()
  }
  func reloadTableData() {
    DataManager.shared.viewController.tableView.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Any thoughts as to why a larger number causes the guard let to fail when running the app, but does not fail in my tests or postman?

**EDIT**

Below is how I am calling the function. I am calling it in viewdidload. It uses a completion handler, so it looks like the following:

```
api.loadData(search: "ibm") { Results in
  self.filteredResults = self.api.storedData.results //stores value in filtered results array
  
  self.tableView.reloadData() //refreshes table view - table view is referencing the filteredResults array
}
```

Comment: Is code above supposed to reproduced the issue? I tried `guard let url = URL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Apple&entity=software&limit=14")` and then `guard let url = URL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Apple&entity=software&limit=500")` and they don't fail.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! Did you test directly in A view controller? The failure only occurs when calling the function in viewdidload. The first link you posted does not throw an error as it is =14, but running the second one on my end does throw an error (=500)

Comment: `guard let url = URL(string:"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Apple&entity=software&limit=14")` the way it's provided in this question will not do anything differently with or without UIViewController (since it has hard-coded URL). Either you are parameterizing this URL somehow, or some other piece of information is missing here
Also "throw an error 500" (which is server error) is very different from guard failing for URL. If you get error 500, it means the server is not accepting your parameter, but it also means that it didn't fail the guard because of large count.

Comment: I added an additional piece of code to show how I am calling the function. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: I found the source of the issue. I was on the incorrect branch, which led to me copying the incorrect code. I have added the updated code. The issue has to do with the parameter I am passing into the URL. When I pass in a value, I receive an error when the number >15. Without the parameter, it works correctly. Any thoughts why a larger number fails when passing in a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many keys missing in the JSON, when you set a limit of more than 20:

- Always use doCatch when decoding JSON and print the `error`, which tells you what went wrong, in your source decoding is failing because of the following error: [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55391123/6576315)

```
    keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "releaseNotes", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "results", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 15", intValue: 15)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"releaseNotes\", intValue: nil) (\"releaseNotes\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

- Try making all variables in the struct `Optional` to fix decoding issue for now.

---

**Make properties optional**

```
struct Response: Codable {
  var resultCount: Int?
  var results: [Result]?
}

struct Result: Codable {
  var screenshotUrls, ipadScreenshotUrls, appletvScreenshotUrls: [String]?
  var artworkUrl60, artworkUrl512, artworkUrl100, artistViewUrl: String?
  var supportedDevices, advisories: [String]?
  var isGameCenterEnabled: Bool?
  var features: [String]?
  var kind, minimumOsVersion, trackCensoredName, fileSizeBytes: String?
  var contentAdvisoryRating: String?
  var genreIds: [String]?
  var primaryGenreName, artistName, trackContentRating, trackName, releaseDate, sellerName, currentVersionReleaseDate, releaseNotes, version: String?
  var primaryGenreId: Int?
  var currency, description: String?
  var price: Double?
  var averageUserRating: Double?
}
```

Put this inside the `if-let` data block:

```
        do {
            let response =  try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.storedData.resultCount = response.resultCount
                self.storedData.results = response.results
                completionHandler(self.storedData)
            }
            
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: Great info. Thanks! When I hardcode the string it works fine regardless of the size added. It only seems to fail when I pass in the search parameter (see updated code). Any thoughts on why it works one way and not the other?

Comment: @nickreps Maybe the "apple" keyword worked but it won't work for "ibm". If this is what you mean - https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=ibm&entity=software&limit=40

Comment: Very weird! It seems to fail for certain parameters, and not others. For example, IBM fails, "games" fails, but apple works. Any thoughts on why that could be? Searching for "IBM" when the result count == 14 works fine, but if the result amount is large it fails.

Comment: @nickreps that's what I said in my answer, refactor your code and capture `error`.  + make those variables optional and it won't fail.

Comment: Ok. I will work at implementing your answer. Is it possible to use a do catch block in guard let, or do I have to convert to if let?

Comment: @nickreps added sample code for reference.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the releaseNotes key from my struct and implementing the do let looks like the way to go. It seems like do let is the best approach in all api calls so an error can be printed. Does that sound correct?